# How to write instanceof with Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, instanceof

I am new in Java 8 Optional. I have to change the following code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getAccount() {
    return 
        Optional.ofNullable(userService.getUserWithAuthorities())
        .map(user -> 
            new ResponseEntity<>(
                new UserDTO(
                    user.getLogin(),
                    null,
                    user.getFirstName(),
                    user.getLastName(),
                    user.getEmail(),
                    "",
                    user.getLangKey(),
                    user.getAuthorities()
                        .stream()
                        .map(Authority::getName)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                ),
                HttpStatus.OK
            )
        )
        .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
}
```

I want to create a different ResponseEntity according to the instance of `user`.
How i can write the equivalent of the following code:

```
if(user instanceof Admin )
{
// my logic
}
else if(user instanceof NormalUser)
{
// my logic
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do it like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getAccount() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(userService.getUserWithAuthorities())
            .map(user -> {
                if (user instanceof Admin) {
                    //...
                }
                return new ResponseEntity<>(new UserDTO(...), HttpStatus.OK);
            })
            .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
    }
```

However, if you can, avoid the `instanceof` operator. Add a `isAdmin` method to your `User` class : in class `Admin`, it would return `true` and in class `NormalUser`, it would return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The way you did it. However, you will have to cast `u` to the type you want.

```
if (u instanceof Admin) {
    Admin a = (Admin) u;
    // your logic
}
```

**Edit:** As of Java 14, you can also do this:

```java
if (u instanceof Admin a) {
    // your logic
}
```

Comment: You mean i can add this logic in new ResponseEntity ?

Comment: Yes, that would go in place of the UserDTO constructor call.

Comment: @Pracade yes, you can.